# What do I need to install to make more packages available under ShareLaTeX?

Tags: packages, sharelatex

I'm hosting a ShareLaTeX instance to enable some colleagues to cooperatively write their papers. Now one of them brought to my attention, that apparently a whole lot of pretty common packages are missing from the installation, prompting a `` LaTeX Error: File `package.sty' not found. `` error.

This happens for e.g. `tikz`, `microtype` and `aastex`. Working are for example `amsmath`, `hyperref` and `graphicx`. I just tried some packages I could think of, these have been chosen quite randomly (apart from being somewhat common).

My ShareLaTeX installation was done via their [Docker image](https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex-docker-image). Is there anything I could try installing within the container to get access to the additional packages without having to upload the sty files into my ShareLaTeX project?

Comment: Welcome! Wouldn't it have been quicker to look at the Quick Install Guide than to ask a question and wait for somebody else to do so?

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I have been actually running this instance for quite some time and I did read the quick start guide at some point in the past, but must've forgotten that this topic is explicitly mentioned there. Just to not look like a QandA-douche, I actually did research this on my own, but I googled more specifically why e.g. tikz is missing in ShareLaTeX by default and could not find the answer that way for the life of me. Sorry for posting such an easy question, but I'm afraid it's a case of not seeing the wood for the trees on my part.

Comment: No problem. Everyone does that sometimes ;). I shouldn't have assumed this wasn't one of those times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read their Quick Start Guard at https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide.

```
docker exec sharelatex tlmgr install scheme-full
```